# Messy database - how to identify and change encoding of existing data in columns?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Recently I changed the encoding for the application from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 (requests, responses, html page encodings etc).

The database is Microsoft SQL Server 2019. The given table has two columns: **Name NVARCHAR(255)** and **Value NVARCHAR(MAX)**. The collation for both columns is **SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS**.

The data is saved with HTML form. All works well **except for displaying some old data fetched from a database** (saved before switching to UTF-8). There are some special characters - for example **€, Œ, œ, Ÿ** - that are displayed now as replacement characters (little empty squares). If I switch page encoding back to ISO-8859-1 again they are displayed properly.

That's because there is a **difference how old saved values and new saved values are stored in database**. The mentioned symbols are 'not visible' in a database client, if they were saved before switching to UTF-8. They are 'visible' if they were saved after switching to UTF-8 (example: '----' vs '-€-Œ-œ-Ÿ').

**My question is** - how to check **what is the encoding of the existing data** (my understanding is that it's UTF-16, as it's the default encoding for NVARCHAR - but then what's the issue with those special characters?) and **is there a way to fix those characters**?

I tried changing column's collation to **Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC** and creating a copy table with **VARCHAR** types and **Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8** collation and copying the data, but no effect.

Comment: As far as SQL Server is concerned the `nvarchar` data type stores UCS-2 data unless the database's default collation is one of the `_SC` (Supplementary Characters) collations, as which point it uses UTF-16 encoding. That doesn't stop applications storing whatever data they want, however, so it sounds like your application isn't actually aware of `nvarchar` data types (or "wide string" as they're sometimes called) and has been explicitly writing iso-8859-1 and/or UTF-8 encoded bytes into the `nvarchar` columns.

Comment: `example: '----' vs '-€-Œ-œ-Ÿ'` suggests that your application has not been using data types correctly. If the above strings were part of an SQL Query, for example, they should be using the `N` prefix that delimited National Character literals, i.e.: `N'----'` and `N'-€-Œ-œ-Ÿ'`. Compare the output of `select N'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ', 'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ'` to see why this matters.

Comment: I see. Database's default colaltion is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS`. As for writing iso-8859-1 and/or UTF-8 encoded bytes into `nvarchar` columns, is it a bad practice? And is there a way to unify/fix database contents?